# Vapor - Create web socket

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm trying to create a small chat application using Vapor but I got stuck.  I am using Socket.IO on ios and I am always getting the error page not found.

Can you please guide me towards identifying my error?

Vapor codes :

```
drop.socket("ws") { req, ws in
print("New WebSocket connected: \(ws)")

// ping the socket to keep it open
try background {
while ws.state == .open {
  try? ws.ping()
  drop.console.wait(seconds: 10) // every 10 seconds
}
}

ws.onText = { ws, text in
print("Text received: \(text)")

// reverse the characters and send back
let rev = String(text.characters.reversed())
try ws.send(rev)
}

ws.onClose = { ws, code, reason, clean in
print("Closed.")
}
}

drop.run()
```

On the client side:

```
func receiveMSGFromServer(){

let u = URL(string: "ws://localhost:8080/ws")
//"http://localhost:8080/"

let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "wss://localhost:8080/ws")!, config: [.log(true), .forcePolling(true)]) //SocketIOClient(socketURL: u!)

socket.emit("ws", ":emptyParam")

socket.on("ws") {data, ack in
  print("Message for you! \(data[0])")
 // ack("I got your message, and I'll send my response")
  socket.emit("response", "Hello!")
}

socket.connect()
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure that socket-io is a generic websocket library. I believe its intended to communicate w/ a proprietary socket library on backend as well. You might want to try starscream or something for communicating with Vapor.

Comment: If answer bellow works, mark this question as resolved

Comment: I had an issue with it not working with SocketIOClient. I tried Starscream and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using `wss` in the `socketURL`.

This will only work if you are hosting the application over TLS (SSL).

Try using just `ws` or hosting the application over TLS.